# Get path to file that defines PowerShell function

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to figure out a way of getting the file path where a PowerShell *function* is defined (eg. Test1 or Test2), rather than the *caller's* path, which would be easily obtained via the `$PSScriptRoot` automatic variable.

Consider the following folder structure:

```
c:\Scripts\Test.ps1
c:\Scripts\Test1\Test1.ps1
c:\Scripts\Test2\Test2.ps1
```

**Test.ps1**

```
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot;
. .\Test1\Test1.ps1;
. .\Test2\Test2.ps1;

Test1;
Test2;
```

**Test1.ps1**

```
function Test1 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
    )
    Write-Host -Object "Entering Test1";
    Write-Host -Object "Exiting Test1";
}
```

**Test2.ps1**

```
function Test2 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
    )
    Write-Host -Object "Test2";
    Write-Host -Object "Exiting Test2";
}
```

I have tried using a variety of properties on the `$PSCmdlet` and `$MyInvocation` automatic variables, but cannot seem to find a way to obtain the path to the file where the function is defined, rather than where the caller is located.

Asked differently, how would I get the path `C:\Scripts\Test1\Test1.ps1` from inside the `Test1` function, when it's called from `Test.ps1`? The same goes for the `Test2.ps1` script, and `Test2` function. How would I get the path `C:\Scripts\Test2\Test2.ps1` from inside the `Test2` function?

Is this not possible because I'm using the `.` call operator, to import the functions into the current session?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think $PSCommandPath has what you're looking for.

Comment: Blargh! You were correct, sir! It's hard to keep track of ... I wish they'd rope it in with the `$PSCmdlet` variable, or something.

Comment: Can you show an example how to call that system var?

Answer (score 21):

Here's another way, get the file that contains the function using function's scriptblock File property:

```
${function:Test1}.File
```

Comment: Good call, doesn't require PSv3.

Comment: Shay, could you please explain this further? It looks like you're getting the function using variable notation?

Comment: Sure, variable notation has two versions. The "standard": $var, and ${var}. In latter, variable names can include any character. An example would be a variable name that contains spaces: ${variable with spaces}.
${} is a get-content equivalent. The function's content is its definition, or scriptblock. ScriptBlocks have a File property which is populated with the file name that contains the function (assuming the function came from a file).

The equivalent of ${function:test1}.File would be: $func = Get-Command test1; $func.ScriptBlock.File