# Powershell functions defined in profile

Tags: powershell, metadata

I have a function called **GreatFuncion1** defined in "profile.ps1"

*loads when powershell launches and works ok*

how can I get the path where this function was defined from Powershell?
usually i'll do this with:

```
(Get-Command -commandtype function -name **GreatFunction1**).Module
```

but in this case it returns $null, so I can't get a path from here...
?is there any other way??
I need to know the path to the file from what some function was loaded...

Comment: It won't be preserved, PowerShell reads the contents of all applicable profile scripts and executes them in-memory, original source file won't be available by the time the function is defined.

Comment: If that's the functionality that you really need, why not create an actual PowerShell Module for your function(s), then simply import that module in your profile? The module can be really barebones even.

Comment: thanks @shenk... but this is for a code profiler/analyser... I need to discover the file origin of a function only by name,,, from the running code... ;-)

Comment: hi @Matias... that is one of the goals... i ineed to know from what profile the function came using the function name... this metadata should be available in the same form as when you do a (Get-Command -Name Update-IscsiTarget ).Module.Path

Answer (score 0):

Try `${function:**GreatFunction1**}.File this should give you the full path for wherever your function is coming from

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16008967/13160707

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Taking what [@nikkelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13160707/nikkelly) mentioned in their answer and generalizing it, you could accomplish this by first accessing the `ScriptBlock` property of the function, and then the `File` property of the ScriptBlock.

Here are two equivalent examples:

```
(Get-ChildItem Function: | Where-Object Name -like "**GreatFunction1**").ScriptBlock.File
```

```
(Get-Command -CommandType Function -Name **GreatFunction1**).ScriptBlock.File
```